# how can I make single variables inside a formula bold?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I got this formula:

```
$$ \hat{p} = h_{\theta}(x) = \sigma(\theta^T x) $$
```

which gives me this:

[image]

But I would like to have some of these variables fat, basically like this:

```
$$ hat{p} = h_{**\theta**}(x) = \sigma(**\theta**^T**x**) $$
```

I have tried to nest it with `\fat{}` but that did not work.

Is it possible to fatten single variables in a formula?

Comment: `\bm{\theta}` (needs `\usepackage{bm}`).

Comment: Unrelated but please also consult [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: thanks! And also thanks for the link, first time ever working in latex for my thesis right now.

Answer (score 1):

`\bm{\theta}`  where `\bm` is defined by `\usepackage{bm}`